# How to reference NPM-installed three.js from another NPM-installed library and/or another JS script?

Tags: javascript, npm, module, three.js

Trying to set up an example of THREE with this [MeshLine](https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine) implementation. Running on VSCode with Live Server extension, port 5500, Firefox. Already tried several combinations of import, require, with or without the type="module" attribute, every time there is a different error. I have the feeling this is because I installed this as NPM modules instead of linking the scripts directly (I did this to be able to use the @types definitions for three), but I just cannot manage to fully understand the JS module ecosystem and variations.

**Question**
Is it possible to use these libraries (actually three.meshline which requires three) via NPM (= without directly linking the scripts) and if yes, how? Alternatively how to reference NPM three from non-NPM three.meshline script?

```
/// index.html

<script src="node_modules/three/build/three.module.js"
    type="module"></script>
<!-- <script src="node_modules/three.meshline/src/THREE.MeshLine.js"
    type="module"></script> -->
<script type="module">
    import("./node_modules/three.meshline/src/THREE.MeshLine.js")
</script>


/// THREE.MeshLine.js

;(function() {
  'use strict'

  var root = this
  var has_require = typeof require !== 'undefined'

  console.log(root.THREE)  // undefined
  console.log(has_require) // false

  var THREE = root.THREE || (has_require && require('three')) // <-- Uncaught TypeError: root is undefined
  if (!THREE) throw new Error('MeshLine requires three.js')   // <-- never managed to pass this test

  // (implementation code here)...

  if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
      exports = module.exports = {
        MeshLine: MeshLine,
        MeshLineMaterial: MeshLineMaterial,
        MeshLineRaycast: MeshLineRaycast,
      }
    }
    exports.MeshLine = MeshLine
    exports.MeshLineMaterial = MeshLineMaterial
    exports.MeshLineRaycast = MeshLineRaycast
  } else {
    root.MeshLine = MeshLine
    root.MeshLineMaterial = MeshLineMaterial
    root.MeshLineRaycast = MeshLineRaycast
  }
}.call(this))
```

Comment: in order to use the without any bundler (like webpack/rollup etc), the packages must have `jsm` modules, and these module files must be publicly accessible (and the `node_modules` folder usually is not)

Comment: @MarianTheisen ThreeJS has *some* jsm modules in three/examples/jsm folder and I saw they mention this in the doc but it's not clear how to use these. MeshLine does not have jsm modules.